# Is there a way to debug the usage of polyfill scripts?

Tags: c#, wpf, polyfills

I am using WPF to display a Openlayers map in a program. But when starting it, i get this error, which doesn't really tell me anything at all:

[The Error-Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D5CF.png)

Interestingly enough i can still load it in Internet Explorer (which is used internally by WPF).

If anyone could tell me how to properly debug this problem i would be quite thrilled.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look here @Moritz https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/tti-polyfill

Comment: In the control, ie is throttled to ie7 rather than ie11. This is likely your problem. You can use a meta attribute on the page to force it into ie11 "edge" mode. Or you could use a xaml island webview instead.